# what does Map means in Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options

Tags: java, tomcat, jaas

so am learning jaas and in the method initialise in logincontext the method is declared as follows

```
public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState,
            Map<String, ?> options)
```

so what does map options and map shared state do?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Are you asking what the `Map` interface is, or what the `sharedState` / `options` arguments are used for?

Comment: What's your exact question? Is it about the meanig of'?'? It is an unbounded wildcard, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html

Comment: i wanna know what is the role of map<strings,?> in sharedstate and options

Comment: The purpose of arguments should be documented. What method are you implementing? Can you link to the documentation?

Comment: Such a `Map<String, ?>` holds key-value pairs where the key is a `String` (probably the name of the option in this case) and the value can be any class (e.g. a `Boolean` for an option that can be switched on or off, or an `Integer` for a value in a specific range). Check the documentation for available options…